# Check if a file is used in PHP

Tags: php

I get a file from my FTP server and I want to know if it is used. I get it with :

```
$handle=fopen("ftp://".$username.":".$password."@".$host.":21".$directory."/".$file, "r");
```

But before use it or change it, I want to know if someone else is reading or updating it. Is there a php function for that please ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

I tried with `flock()` but it doesn't work, it always pass through `echo check` :

```
if (!flock($handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB, $wouldblock)) {
    if (!$wouldblock) {
        echo "check";
    } else {
        echo "test";
    }
} else {
    echo "try";
}
```

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: @M.I. I tried with it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: An FTP will not generally expose this information. You probably need to set up SSH instead.

Comment: @apokryfos Ah ok :/ Thanks

Comment: try to use sftp, i am not sure if it will work, but it should. http://php.net/manual/ro/function.ssh2-sftp.php